# Mapping F13, F14, F15

Tags: macos, keyboard, software-recommendation

I am a programmer and I would like to map all the unused function keys (from F13 to F19) on my Apple Keyboard to some useful chars like parenthesis: <kbd>{</kbd>, <kbd>}</kbd>,  <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd> and quotes

Is there a free software for Mac OS X 10.7+ that I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: What Apple keyboard do you have with up to the F19 key?

Comment: This one most likely : http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB110LL/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-english-usa?fnode=56

Comment: Yep :-) I have the extended Apple keyboard

Comment: there might be an answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13969/mapping-external-keyboard-keys-to-mac-keys?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) (previously named KeyRemap4MacBook):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F13, KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT, VK_SHIFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F14, KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT, VK_SHIFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F15, KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F16, KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Change for example `KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT, VK_SHIFT` to whatever key combination inserts `{` in your keyboard layout.

Answer (score 3):

Just try BetterTouchTool, you can do almost everything you want!

[Better Touch Tool](https://blog.boastr.net)

Just download and install it. Then run it and select "Keyboard" tab where you can configure buttons. Click on "Add new shortcut" and then just specify your shortcut - in your case "Keyboard shortcut" will be F13 and "Trigger other Keyboard shortcut" will be { And do it for next keys like F15 etc...

You also can configure this shortcuts only for your IDE. In left panel "Select Application" click on "+" and select your IDE, then just configure your shortcuts for your IDE..

Ohh and you can have a problem to mapping F14-F15 keys, because in default OS X use it for monitor brightness.. So you have to go to the Mac Preference - keyboard - shortcut - monitor/display - uncheck f14 and f15 keys and enjoy!

I'm using it also for my Magic Mouse configuration. For example middle click and other shortcuts and gestures that I was missing. It also supports window snapping and much more. It's just on of the must have application on your Mac.

My recommendation is to go to the BetterTouchTool settings and check "Launch BetterTouchTool on startup"

Happy Coding ;-)

Comment: How do you accomplish function key remapping with Better Touch Tool?.

Comment: See my edited answer. It's really easy and intuitive to use it.

Answer (score -3):

What about karabiner app?

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Hope it will help

Comment: This app is already noted as the solution, as provided by the accepted answer, with a full private.xml to go along with it. What does your answer add that the existing answer does not provide?

Comment: @grgarside to be fair the accepted answer says "KeyRemap4MacBook" which Alejandro may not have known is the same software

Comment: @andrewtweber you are right :)